# Invisible div to the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a div invisible to the browser. I mean, i have a div which it's something like a mark and i have another div that contain a google maps.

I put the next code for better understanding.

```
<div id="marc" class="marco"></div>
<div id="canvas-map"></div>
```

Style:

```
.marco{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url("vintaje-montaje.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The problem is the next: the div than works us a mark ("#marc") works fine. It's look fine. But as is ahead of the other div, i can't use the google maps.

I thought use jQuery and use `e.preventDefault()` when the mouse is over the div  what not work.

Help me please.

Thanks and forgive me for my bad English.

Comment: Why do you want to put your image over the google maps div?

Comment: Chances are, that since you are using Absolute positioning, that element sits as the top z-index since you have not defined a z-index for "#canvas-map"

Give the canvas-map div a position of absolute and set its z-index higher than the marc div. Or, simply make canvas map a child of marc an give marc a z-index of 1 and canvas-map a z-index of like 10.

Comment: For aesthetic issues! pointer-events: none works!! thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: pointer-events does not work on any version of IE except the last version. If you care about accessibility - dont use pointer-events. Use z-index to properly structure the DOM. pointer-events is the equivalent of using !important - they are both hacky ways to work with a DOM structure that was poorly thought out. pointer-events are also buggy as hell on several mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks Korgue for the councils. Of course i care about accessibility. I will try to do it the way you say.

Answer (score 3):

[`pointer-evens: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) will allow your mouse / touch events to pass through `.marco` to the underlying elements:

```
.marco{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url("vintaje-montaje.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: Thanks! It works! I cannot mark the answer as correct because my reputation. Thanks again